# Fix gradual :hover glow in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have some css that gradually changes the background colour of an element when hovered on and the links below it.

It works perfect in Chrome and IE9+ but in FF it only works on the element you hover on and it instead immediately changes the colour on the elements below

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V8H6T/15/)

I'm guessing the problem lies somewhere here:

```
.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

What do I need to change/add to get it to work properly in FF

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the same transition on the element(s) below as well.

I'm guessing you want the lines in your example to have the same effect. I've updated the example with this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/westman/V8H6T/14/).

Edit:
I added the transition CSS to all classes that handles the border you use to draw the lines

```
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
```

Comment: What did you add to the code to get that to work? I can't tell what you've added!

Comment: I updated my answer with the explanation. I hope it helps you